# CDI interface-based bean in JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, interface, jsf-2, cdi

I'm having troubles working with CDI in JSF project. I cannot force CDI to inject *interface-based* bean into JSF file.

```
@Named
public class ClassBasedNamedBean {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Class-based Hello World!";
    }
}

@Named
public interface InterfaceBasedNamedBean {
    public String getMessage();
}

public class InterfaceBasedNamedBeanImpl implements InterfaceBasedNamedBean {
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Interface-based Hello World!";
    }
}
```

I can use both beans in WebServlet environment:

```
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    private ClassBasedNamedBean classBasedNamedBean;

    @Inject
    private InterfaceBasedNamedBean interfaceBasedNamedBean;

    protected void doGet(...) ... {
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("classBasedNamedBean: " + classBasedNamedBean.getMessage());
        pw.println("interfaceBasedNamedBean: " + interfaceBasedNamedBean.getMessage());

        // Output:
        // classBasedNamedBean: Class-based Hello World!
        // interfaceBasedNamedBean: Interface-based Hello World!
    }
}
```

But `interfaceBasedNamedBean` is not available in JSF page:

```
<p>ClassBasedNamedBean: #{classBasedNamedBean.message}</p>
<p>InterfaceBasedNamedBean: #{interfaceBasedNamedBean.message}</p>

Output:
<p>ClassBasedNamedBean: Class-based Hello World!</p>
<p>InterfaceBasedNamedBean: </p>
```

How could I fix this issue? Does JSF require some explicit configuration for `interfaceBasedNamedBean`?

Answer (score 2):

As my best guess:

I don't think that this is mentioned in the spec, but I'm pretty sure that `@Named` is not intended to be used on interfaces.

After all, it's just a matching between a type and an EL-name - and it seems as if the EL resolver can't find anything (concrete) under the name of the interface.

So, try annotating the implementation, not the interface - this should work. If you need to be flexible with various implementations of the same bean type - inject it in a controller bean and make that bean accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You set `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager` as your BeanManager?

What happens if you add `@Named("InterfaceBasedNamedBean")` to your Class Definition and remove the annotation from the interface? For what reason are you using the annotations anyways? CDI is not requiring them in contrast to spring.

Have you tried using a producer method?

Comment: `@Named` is required to access the bean from within a JSF page ;-)

Comment: How can I set proper BeanManager for JSF (I'm quite new to both, JSF and CDI and surprisingly Google doesn't return clear answer in first 3 results :])? I guess I'll have to set it up in `web.xml` or `faces-config.xml`. This seems to be the most probably solution.
(JSF impl: Mojarra, CDI impl: weld, AS: GlassFish)

Comment: If you are on a standard JEE 6 environment (like Glassfish) dont worry about the BeanManager configration, that should be all set. Try to move @Named to implementation, this might be a workaround. Should that not work any better, make the bean accessible through a controller until we figured the real cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding scope to your bean with @RequestScoped, for example. From Weld docs:

> The @Named annotation is not what makes the class a bean. Most classes in a bean archive are already recognized as beans. The @Named annotation just makes it possible to reference the bean from the EL, most commonly from a JSF view.

Answer (score 0):

CDI defines @Named as a String-based qualifier. A qualifier's purpose is to distinguish which implementation to use at the injection point. The @Named's javadoc gives an example:

```
public class Car {
   @Inject @Named("driver") Seat driverSeat;
   @Inject @Named("passenger") Seat passengerSeat;
   ...
}
```

Thus @Named must annotate a specific implementation.

@Named as a way to use CDI beans in JSF views can be seen as a secondary function. @Named is not "@Inject for JSF" as it may seem to be.